# call a function within exports.run()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file called something.js with this code:

```
exports.run = (args) => {
  function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}
```

Now I want to call `foo` from another file.
My code looks like this with errors attached as comments:

```
const something = require("./something.js"); 
module.exports = {
  callFoo: function() {
    something.foo(); //TypeError: something.foo is not a function
    something.run.foo(); //TypeError: something.run.foo is not a function
}
```

Is it possible to call such a function which is apparently not a function?

Comment: Why are you defining that `foo` function inside the `run` function in the first place? And never call it?

Comment: it's not my complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign an arrow function to `exports.run` and in that function, you define the `foo` function, but this function is not reachable from outside of the arrow function. Yur code is nearly equivalent to:

```
exports.run = function(args) {
   function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
   }
}
```

You most likely want to write:

```
exports.run =  {
   foo() {
    console.log("foo");
   }
}
```

Or

```
exports.run =  {
   foo : function() {
    console.log("foo");
   }
}
```

Comment: facepalm. Now that you say it, it makes sense, of course. I was too fixated on solving my problem without thinking of the whole thing. Thank you.